# usepackage and making macros in ipython notebook

Tags: latex, ipython

How can user macros and packages be included in the latex rendered in markdown cells in ipython?

e.g.:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{kms}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{km~s}^{-1}}
```

Comment: I'm curious. Have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to define macros in cells with markdown. Just put the `\newcommand` between `$`'s:

```
$\newcommand{kms}{{\mathrm{km~s}^{-1}}}$
```

(Note that I removed the `\ensuremath` command, as it is not accessible.)

In any following statement (in the whole notebook) you can call the macro (in a markdown cell only, of course):

```
$\kms$
```

I do not know a way to include extra packages :( If you ever learn how, I would also encourage you to use the [siuntx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to format units.

Answer (score 2):

The Html notebook use [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render LaTeX, I suggest reading its doc to know wether it is possible and how.